# When scroll direction is horizontal, text overflow is not working. How can I TextOverflow.ellipsis work properly?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to overflow long text in a column with Card. Text must overflow width of Card. Scroll Direction set to Axis.horizontal for that reason TextOverflow does not pass to second line or overlow. Do you have any suggestions?

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                                                  scrollDirection:
                                                      Axis.horizontal,
                                                  child: Row(
                                                    children: [
                                                      Column(
                                                        children: [
                                                          Flexible(
                                                            flex: 5,
                                                            child: SizedBox(
                                                              width: 80.w,
                                                              height: 80.h,
                                                              child: Card(
                                                                  elevation: 2,
                                                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                                      borderRadius:
                                                                          BorderRadius.circular(
                                                                              10.r)),
                                                                  child: Center(
                                                                    child: Image
                                                                        .network(
                                                                      productsProvider
                                                                          .randomProducts[
                                                                              itemIndex]
                                                                          .photo,
                                                                      fit: BoxFit
                                                                          .cover,
                                                                    ),
                                                                  )),
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                          Flexible(
                                                            child: Text(
                                                              productsProvider
                                                                  .randomProducts[
                                                                      itemIndex]
                                                                  .name,
                                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                                  fontSize:
                                                                      10.sp),
                                                              overflow:
                                                                  TextOverflow
                                                                      .ellipsis,
                                                              maxLines: 2,
                                                            ),
                                                          )
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                );
```

[Here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlriZ.png)

This is the code that everybody can see what happens. It is not complicated but I did not find a solution to work properly.

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: strings.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Column(
            children: [
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8)),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(strings[index]),
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8, left: 8),
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 80,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            itemCount: 2,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int itemIndex) {
                              return SingleChildScrollView(
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                child: Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Column(
                                      children: [
                                        Flexible(
                                          flex: 5,
                                          child: SizedBox(
                                            width: 80,
                                            height: 80,
                                            child: Card(
                                                elevation: 2,
                                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius.circular(
                                                            10)),
                                                child: Center(
                                                  child: Image.network(
                                                    'https://ayb.akinoncdn.com/products/2019/04/24/21736/788e20d1-81ca-42da-a6bb-25c2698fafaa_size780x780_quality60_cropCenter.jpg',
                                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                  ),
                                                )),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Flexible(
                                          child: Text(
                                            'Osmanlı şahzade badem ezmesi. Üretimi tecrübeye sabit',
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                            maxLines: 2,
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            }),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
```

Comment: hello. please provide a simple runnable code. thanks

Comment: Hi. I edited my question you can find it

Comment: List<String> strings = [
    'Coğrafi İşaretli Ürünler',
    'Doğal Ürünler',
    'Vegan Ürünler'
  ];

  final ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the reason behind is that you have set the `scrollDirection` to `horizontal` and inside it you are using a **Row** as well which also has a `horizontal axis` `direction` and after that you are passing your Text widget inside **Flexible** and according to **Flexible** widget property it will stretch it self according to it's child size. In your case **Flexible** has a `unbounded` width so it's expanding it self according to it's `child` which result a `full length text` to appear and because it's showing full content `TextOverflow.ellipsis` will not work.

Basically to `solve` this you have to wrap your **Text** widget to a **SizedBox** so that it can have a `bounded width`.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a perception. That works for me.

Comment: Pleased to help you and upvote also. Thanks :)